# Opens a process with Popen cant close it ( need to run Ros command in cmd)

Tags: python, popen, ros

I need to save some image files from my simulation at different times. So my idea was to open a subprocess save some image files and close it .

```
import subprocess

cmd = "rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=camera/depth/points"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

When it comes to closing I tried different things:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

cmd = "rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=camera/depth/points"
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

command did not execute , so it doesn't work for me. I also tried a solution with `psutil` and it didn't work neither...

Comment: can't you drop `shell=True` and pass the arguments as list? that could just solve your problems.

Comment: BTW if you kill it just after having run it you have the possiblity that it closes without doing anything useful. You have to wait a bit before killing it, if this is useful at all...

Comment: yeah i know i tried this in my larger file it normally starts saving images when i drive to an object and it should stop when the robot turning around. But all time it saves images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably don't need `shell=True` here, which is the cause of your problems. I suspect that when you kill the process group in your second snippet, the shell process is killed *before* the process you want to run has a chance to start...

Try to pass the parameters as a list of strings (so you don't need `shell=True`), wait a bit, and use `terminate` on the `Popen` object. You don't need process group, or `psutil` to kill the process & its children, just plain old `terminate()` on the process object does the trick.

```
cmd = ["rosrun","pcl_ros","pointcloud_to_pcd","input:=camera/depth/points"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
time.sleep(1)  # maybe needed to wait the process to do something useful
proc.terminate()
```

Note that `proc.terminate()` tries to exit gracefully where `proc.kill()` would have just killed the process (there's a difference under Un*x systems, not under Windows)

Another plea for "do not use `shell=True` unless forced at gunpoint".

Comment: It seems that `p.kill()` abruptly kills the program, leaving dangling `rostopic`s around. I used `p.terminate()` instead, which properly terminates and cleans up the ROS program just like doing `Ctrl-c` in your terminal.

Comment: oh, you're right. It's the same on windows, but not the same on Linux. Edited. thanks.